# aggregate acknowledging message to rabbitmq in camel

Tags: apache-camel, rabbitmq

I am using `rabbitmq` component in camel. I have a following route:

```
        public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("rabbitmq://localhost:5672/test_op?queue=out_queue&routingKey=test_out&username=guest&password=guest" +
                        "&autoAck=false&durable=true&exchangeType=direct&autoDelete=false&exchangePattern=InOut")
                        .aggregate(constant(true), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
                        .completionSize(2000).completionTimeout(60000).eagerCheckCompletion()                       
                        .process(new Processor() {
                            @Override
                            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                                Message m = exchange.getIn();
                                org.apache.camel.TypeConverter tc = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter();
                                String strValue = tc.convertTo(String.class, m.getBody());
                                System.out.println("[[out_queue]]: "  + strValue);
                            }
                        });
            }
```

Problem is that the use of `aggregate` is acknowledging the message to rabbitmq even before `process()` is called. I want to acknowledge message only when `process()` execution is successful, and not when `aggregate` is invoked. How can I achieve this?

FYI: Without `aggregate` this route works as expected. That means it acknowledges message only when `process()` is executed successfully.